# Formula for finding between the 2 dates whether Leap Year comes in-between

Tags: excel

How do I calculate whether the Year used between the 2 dates falls Leap Year or not.

Example: If Date1 = 02/02/2015 and Date2 = 03/01/2016.

So, if we calculate then result should be "Leap Year" but if we use Date2 = 02/01/2016 then result would be "No Leap Year".

So, if the date2 is crossing the 02/29/16 then only it give the result "Leap Year" else no.

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that the creators of Excel (whoever they are) have already answered this one.

Comment: @Strawberry - Excel thinks 29-Feb-1900 is a valid date so I'm guessing not (old throwback to Lotus compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little harsh to loop each and every date of the interval.
This function will only loop each year:

```
Public Function DatesOfLeapYear(ByVal Date1 As Date, ByVal Date2 As Date) As Boolean

    Dim LeapYear            As Boolean

    Do
        If DateDiff("d", Date1, DateSerial(Year(Date1), 3, 1)) > 0 Then
            If Day(DateSerial(Year(Date1), 2, 29)) = 29 Then
                LeapYear = True
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        Date1 = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Date1)
    Loop Until Date1 >= Date2

    DatesOfLeapYear = LeapYear

End Function
```

It returns True/False as is, but you can of course modify it to returns an explicit result or format the output.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will work from 1 Mar 1900 through 24 November 4770

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(Date1&":"&Date2)))=29)*(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT(Date1&":"&Date2)))=2)),"Leap Year","No Leap Year")
```

It looks for the existence of 29 Feb between Date1 and Date2.

A VBA routine would not have those date limitations.  The following checks to see if any year from Date1 to Date2 is a leap year; and if it is, if that date is between date1 and date2.  This returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which you can then use in an IF function to return what you want.

```
Option Explicit
Function IsLeapYear(DT1 As Date, DT2 As Date) As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    Dim DT As Date

For I = Year(DT1) To Year(DT2)
    DT = DateSerial(I, 2, 29)
    If Day(DT) = 29 And _
        DT >= DT1 And _
        DT <= DT2 Then
            IsLeapYear = True
            Exit Function
    End If
Next I

End Function
```

Comment: Smart starting that at Mar 1, 1900!

Comment: Thank you so much Ron for the answer. It really work very nicely and without error.

Comment: @Sumeet Glad to help.  Since it is working well for you, I would appreciate it if you could mark my response as the Answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> if the date2 is crossing the 02/29/16 then only it give the result "Leap Year"

If `Date1` is in A1 and `Date2` in A2 please try:

```
=IF(AND(A1<DATE(2016,2,29),A2>DATE(2016,2,29)),"Leap Year","No Leap Year")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function LeapTest(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As String
    Dim dEarly As Date, dLate As Date
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, yr As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim d As Date

    dEarly = wf.Min(d1, d2)
    dLate = wf.Max(d1, d2)
    yr = Year(dEarly)
    For d = dEarly To dLate
        If Format(d, "mm/dd") = "02/29" Then
            LeapTest = "Leap Year"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next d
    LeapTest = "Not Leap Year"
End Function
```

It simply walks thru the date range looking for February 29th.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=LeapTest(A1,B1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

*Examples:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a leap year at least once every 8 years so it should be sufficient to look within the next 8 years for the next `leap day` on or after `Date1` and see if that day is within the date range

This formula will do that

`=IF(B2>=EOMONTH(A2,MATCH(29,INDEX(DAY(EOMONTH(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:96"))-1)),0),0)-1),"Leap Year","No Leap Year")`

where `A2` contains `Date1` and `B2` contains `Date2`

That formula should work for [almost] any valid date range in `Excel` - it even recognises that `1900` is not a leap year